# Recuperar radio button selecionado usado RecyclerView

Tags: android

Estou tentando fazer um `RecyclerView`, onde cada *recycleritem* possua 3 opções de *radio button*.

Cada um dos *radio butttons* esta relacionado a um item da lista de objetos que foi passado para o adapter como parâmetro.

Como eu faço pra pegar a seleção do *radio button* selecionado? Tenho que fazer alguma coisa com os *radios buttons* no método `onBindViewHolder`?

Abaixo, segue o meu adapter:

```
public class LikeListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LikeListAdapter.LikeItemViewHolder> {

    private List<Goals> goalsList;

    public LikeListAdapter(List<Goals> goalsList) {
        this.goalsList = goalsList;
    }

    @Override
    public LikeItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        // Inflate the custom layout
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_like, parent, false);
        return new LikeItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LikeItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Goals goals = goalsList.get(position);
        if (goals != null && getItemCount() > 0) {
            holder.goalsDescriptionTextView.setText(goals.getDescription());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return goalsList.size();
    }

    public class LikeItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        @Bind(R.id.description_goalsTextView)
        TextView goalsDescriptionTextView;
        @Bind(R.id.happy_radio)
        RadioButton happyRadioButton;
        @Bind(R.id.soso_radio)
        RadioButton sosoRadioButton;
        @Bind(R.id.angry_radio)
        RadioButton angryRadioButton;
        @Bind(R.id.radio_like)
        RadioGroup radioLike;

        public LikeItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            radioLike.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            Log.e("group","" + group);
            Log.e("checkedId","" + checkedId);
            switch (group.getId()) {
                case (R.id.happy_radio):
                    Log.e("aqui", "happy");
                    break;
                case (R.id.soso_radio):
                    Log.e("aqui", "soso");
                    break;
                case (R.id.angry_radio):
                    Log.e("aqui", "angry");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Em que momento você quer pegar? Acredito que você pode usar o `LayoutManager` para recuperar o `ViewHolder` e buscar o valor do `RadioButton` que está marcado. O método `onBindViewHolder` é apenas para popular os valores do modelo nas `Views` da lista.

Comment: Eu gostaria de pegar no momento que eu seleciono uma das opções de radio button.

Comment: Minha sugestão é registrar o `Adapter` como o `Listener` do evento, ou o próprio `ViewHolder` com uma referência para o modelo relativo ao item, e no caso, atualizar o modelo que está associado a linha em vez de querer recuperar o valor por fora.

Comment: Desculpe se eu tiver sendo muito dumb, mas como faço isso?

Comment: Posso montar uma resposta, mas deve demorar um pouquinho pra fechar.

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão é atualizar o modelo a cada evento e depois buscar essa informação direta do modelo ao invés de procurar nas `Views`. Isso pode ser feito de uma maneira bem simples:

## 1) Registrar o Adapter como `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener`

Nesse caso, precisamos registrar o `Adapter` ao invés do `ViewHolder` e além disso, guardar a posição do item no item da linha por uma `tag`.

```
public class LikeListAdapter extends ... implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    // Todo resto do código continua o mesmo

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LikeItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Goals goals = goalsList.get(position);

        if (goals != null && getItemCount() > 0) {
            holder.goalsDescriptionTextView.setText(goals.getDescription());

            // Registrar o Adapter como o OnCheckedChangeListener
            holder.radioLike.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            // Guardar a posicao do item como uma tag
            holder.radioLike.setTag(R.layout.recycler_item_like, position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        int position = (Integer) group.getTag(R.layout.recycler_item_like);

        Goals goals = goalsList.get(position);
        String checkedItem = null;

        switch (checkedId) {
            case (R.id.happy_radio):
                checkedItem = "happy";
                break;
            case (R.id.soso_radio):
                checkedItem = "soso";
                break;
            case (R.id.angry_radio):
                checkedItem = "angry";
                break;
        }

        // Setar o valor no goals
    }
}
```

## 2) Recuperar o valor direto do `Adapter`

Pra recuperar o valor, basta recuperar o item direto do `Adapter` e buscar o item.